# SQL - if value is >1 look back row when value was = 0 for value

Tags: sql

I have the following table output:

| PLANT_SYS | PEGGING_LEVEL_NO | DEMAND_ORDER_NUMBER | SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM | ASSEMBLY_WO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | H806145376 | 107973812 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 1 | 107973812 | 107975466 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 2 | 107975466 | 107981206 | 107975466 |
| 3 | 3 | 107981206 | 87688107 | 107981206 |
| 3 | 3 | 107981206 | 88597377 | 107981206 |
| 3 | 2 | 107975466 | H024435900RT | 107975466 |
| 3 | 0 | H790880014GT3 | 108063690 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 1 | 108063690 | 88596228 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 1 | 108063690 | 108064890 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88168775 | 108064890 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88168776 | 108064890 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88597385 | 108064890 |

What I am trying to achieve is when the value in the column PEGGING_LEVEL_NO is >1 look back and return the last value when PEGGING_LEVEL_NO was =0 from SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM. so the table would look like this with the column Required Value added:

| PLANT_SYS | PEGGING_LEVEL_NO | DEMAND_ORDER_NUMBER | SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM | ASSEMBLY_WO | Required_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | H806145376 | 107973812 | 107973812 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 1 | 107973812 | 107975466 | 107973812 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 2 | 107975466 | 107981206 | 107975466 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 3 | 107981206 | 87688107 | 107981206 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 3 | 107981206 | 88597377 | 107981206 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 2 | 107975466 | H024435900RT | 107975466 | 107973812 |
| 3 | 0 | H790880014GT3 | 108063690 | 108063690 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 1 | 108063690 | 88596228 | 108063690 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 1 | 108063690 | 108064890 | 108063690 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88168775 | 108064890 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88168776 | 108064890 | 108063690 |
| 3 | 2 | 108064890 | 88597385 | 108064890 | 108063690 |

at the moment I have the following query:

```
   SELECT
   plant_sys,
   pegging_level_no,
   demand_order_number,
   supply_order_num,
   CASE WHEN pegging_level_no = 0 THEN (supply_order_num) ELSE demand_order_number end AS Assembly_WO
FROM
   og_surf_snop_dm.sop_plan_calc_cp_t 
   WHERE  PLANT_SYS = '0003'

ORDER BY
   pegging_seq_2 ASC,
   pegging_level_no ASC;
```

I am hoping the above is possible but if not I have also been trying to do is use the example from this post:
[SQL - check previous row until the requested value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835082/sql-check-previous-row-until-the-requested-value-is-found)
But I can not get it to work with the code I have.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

***********UPDATE************
Thanks you avb for looking at this, I have tried to add an ordering column, but I don't really know what I am doing here to make this work tbh!! I have tried the following :

```
SELECT plant_sys,
   pegging_level_no,
   demand_order_number,
   supply_order_num,
       max(nullif(PEGGING_LEVEL_NO, 2)) over (partition by plant_sys) as imputed_status
from og_surf_snop_dm.sop_plan_calc_cp_t
```

output being:

| PLANT_SYS | PEGGING_LEVEL_NO | DEMAND_ORDER_NUMBER | SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM | ASSEMBLY_WO | IMPUTED_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 10200466 | 10200466 | 10200466 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 107992155 | H035731700 | 107992155 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 107992155 | H035731800 | 107992155 | 4 |

and also

```
SELECT
   plant_sys,
   pegging_level_no,
   demand_order_number,
   supply_order_num,
   CASE WHEN pegging_level_no = 0 THEN (supply_order_num) ELSE demand_order_number end AS Assembly_WO,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY plant_sys) AS Position
FROM
   og_surf_snop_dm.sop_plan_calc_cp_t
```

output being:

| PLANT_SYS | PEGGING_LEVEL_NO | DEMAND_ORDER_NUMBER | SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM | ASSEMBLY_WO | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 10200466 | 10200466 | 10200466 | 2126 |
| 3 | 2 | 107992155 | H035731700 | 107992155 | 37582 |
| 3 | 2 | 107992155 | H035731800 | 107992155 | 2127 |

**************UPDATE 05/05*****************
I have gotten closer with the below code, but the required_Value is still showing 'NULL' for the items where the PEGGING_LEVEL_NO >0

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY plant_sys) AS Position,
    CASE WHEN pegging_level_no = 0 THEN (supply_order_num) ELSE demand_order_number end AS Assembly_WO, -- ignore
    max(Required_Value) over (partition by PLANT_SYS, grp) as Required_Value
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when Required_Value is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by PLANT_SYS order by 27 Desc) as grp
      from 
        (select 
            t.*
            ,Case When PEGGING_LEVEL_NO = 0 Then SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM END as Required_Value 
        FROM og_surf_snop_dm.sop_plan_calc_cp_t t
         WHERE  PLANT_SYS = '0003')  t
     ) t;
```

Comment: `pegging_seq_2` is not included in the sample data table ! Also, what `DBMS` you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an ordering column (identity seed, row_number etc.) of some sort added to the table to maintain the row order but the code referenced in that link will work.

Once you have an ordering column established you can use the below code which is borrowed from the other post you referenced.

In my example I created a column called "RowNumber" which is used to create the "grp" column which in turn is used to partition the Required_Value column.

```
select 
    t.PLANT_SYS
    ,t.PEGGING_LEVEL_NO
    ,t.DEMAND_ORDER_NUMBER
    ,t.SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM
    ,t.ASSEMBLY_WO
    ,max(Required_Value)  over (partition by PLANT_SYS, grp) as Required_Value
from (select t.*
             ,sum(case when Required_Value is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by PLANT_SYS order by RowNumber) as grp
      from 
        (select 
            *
            ,Case When PEGGING_LEVEL_NO = 0 Then SUPPLY_ORDER_NUM END as Required_Value 
        FROM og_surf_snop_dm.sop_plan_calc_cp_t
         WHERE  PLANT_SYS = '0003')  t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hey avb, thank you so much for looking at this I really appreciate it!! I have tried to add an ordering column, but I don't really know what I am doing here to make this work!! I have added an update on my question as I ran out of space trying to reply here. I appreciate you having looked into this

Comment: Galmighty, it looks like you had the right syntax with row_number. The purpose of this is to preserve the order of the rows. You might not be able to use the PLANT_SYS value for your row_number code but you could try using "(select 1)" instead. e.g. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1) ) AS Position. Once you have the row_number established you use that to partition the data here:  sum(case when Required_Value is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by PLANT_SYS order by Position/RowNumber) as grp.

Comment: Hey avb, thank you for sticking with me!! I have updated the above again, I have it close but not sure where I am going wrong now. Note the position column is in column 27 as I can not add this to the table at the moment. As mentioned above where PEGGING_LEVEL_NO is >0 it is still just displaying 'NULL'

Comment: Welcome! You've got the statement in the wrong place. : )  You need to put the "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY plant_sys) AS Position," in the inner most sub-query (put it right below the column REQUIRED_VALUE).  Then you replace the static value "27" with the the column name "Position".  That row number needs to be generated before using it in the "grp" column statement. Also, Order By Desc might not give you the same results as Order By ASC so check the difference.

Comment: utterly brilliant that worked great!! thanks again. I do have one last question, is it possible to order the data from the table before passing the above argument by :      ORDER BY
   pegging_seq_2 ASC,
   pegging_level_no ASC I have tried to add it in but could not get it to work. Basically, order the table and then pass the query to the new table order without creating a new table in the database? is that possible?